# I want to upload a IMS Content Zip File Under a Course Section in Moodle through API

Tags: php, web-services, plugins, moodle

I want to upload a IMS Content Zip File under a section of a course in Moodle. Is it possible to do with Custom Web Services or Plugins? If so can anyone help me with giving the proper reosource of the custom plugin? Thank You

I tried to upload it under a forum of a course using some resources from StackOverflow